# Tool for downloading/importing WSDL-files for a JAX-WS client

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf

I'm consuming a webservice where the WSDL file contains imports to other wsdl and xsd schemas, e.g:

```
<import namespace="http://my.api.com/" location="http://other.server.com:8888/context/services/MyService?wsdl=1"/>
```

which in turn can import other files

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://my.api.com/" schemaLocation="http://other.server.com:8888/context/services/MyService?xsd=1"/>
```

The client is generated by cxf with a maven plugin. The main WSDL file is added as a classpath resource. However, at runtime it appears that the client actually needs access to other.server.com:8888 to resolve the WSDL completely. So the question is, does a tool exist for importing and resolving all URLs in a WSDL so that it is not dependent absolute server URLs in other imports in the WSDL, and suitable for including in a client project?

We do not control the WSDL, so we can't change it in the source.

Edit: Looking for a tool that works on Linux

Comment: It appears that this is possible with SoapUI, although I would prefer a command line tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751847.aspx) from Windows SDK.

```
svcutil /t:metadata http://service/metadataEndpoint
```

> This tool *locates* or *discovers*, one or more related documents that describe a particular XML Web service using the Web Services Description Language (WSDL).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly. I'm having my battles with Jax-ws/SOAP too. :)

If you need to generate the java classes needed to call the webservice you can use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). Inside it you have a wsdl2java. You can use it on linux.
Another option in Java SDK, on the bin folder there's the wsimport that you can use it too.

Edit: You can change the final URL at runtime using the Service class created by Apache CXF.

```
new SomeRandomJaxWSService(new URL(wsdl),new QName(namespace, serviceName))
```

Comment: The problem is not to generate the files, but to resolve the internal namespace references to local, not remote URIs when generating them.